# AJAX: sending string, which includes &

Tags: javascript, jquery, escaping, urlencode

Short question, I am sending ajax request after pressing a button. A string might contain & and if it does, everything after & is treated as a name of second parameter. I tried to use encodeURI(string) but it did not work. How to handle this properly?

My code without experiments:

```
   <input class="refreshButton" type="button" value="refresh" onclick="$('#container').load('/some/path', {string: $('#string').val()});"/></td>
```

Cheers

Comment: That shouldn't happen. Since you are passing an object as the second argument, it should be escaped automatically.

Comment: @Quentin well it happens, when I check the requests which is being sent, there are two parameters as well

Answer (score 0):

**Don't** Try the escape() function:

`$('#container').load('/some/path', {string: escape($('#string').val())})`

e: Whoops

Comment: Don't use `escape`, it is deprecated